# Customizer: Unique identifier that distinguishes which image upload control is uploading an image

Tags: theme-development, customization, uploads, theme-customizer

In the Theme Customizer, I've got a custom `add_action('wp_handle_upload', 'upscale_responsive_bg_imgs')` which upscales responsive background images when uploaded from the theme customizer.  It's working as expected but it has the unwanted effect of upscaling logo images uploaded (they should be natural size of course, not upscaled).

The `$_POST` data is very simply the following, which lacks any unique identifier for the originating field.  Is there any chance of useful metadata that I can key off of being stuffed somewhere else in `$GLOBALS`?

```
(
    [name] => mystiqu_template_screenshot.jpg
    [action] => upload-attachment
    [_wpnonce] => 92fec00835
    [post_data] => Array
        (
            [theme] => pure
        )

)
```

Comment: I get an extra `[context] => custom-background` in the `post_data` part when I upload a background image with the Theme Customizer on the Twenty Twelve theme. Notice that `wp_handle_upload` is a filter not an action.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the tipoff from @birgire in the comment, I was able to locate two things, an example of an implementation that includes `context`, here (also of note is that the Github gist has code for the very useful ability to access any image uploaded from this context previously!

https://gist.github.com/eduardozulian/4739075

```
/**
 * Example of inserting a section called "Branding" with a
 * context-based image uploader
 */
$wp_customize->add_section( 'my_branding', array(
    'title'    => __( 'Branding', '' ),
    'priority' => 30,
) );

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'my_logo', array(
    'capability'  => 'edit_theme_options'
) );

$wp_customize->add_control( new My_Customize_Image_Reloaded_Control( $wp_customize, 'my_logo', array(
    'label'     => __( 'Logo', '' ),
    'section'   => 'my_branding',
    'settings'  => 'my_logo',
    'context'   => 'my-custom-logo'
) ) );
```